# Change the duration of html input validation messages

Tags: html, validation, input

```
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Please enter only alphabets or numbers or one of the special characters period(.), underscore(_), hyphen(-) and make sure it starts and ends with an alphabet or a number" required>
```

This validation message is being displayed for short period, as the message is long it should have stayed for long, but it disappears after few seconds.

How to manage the duration ?

Answer (score 0):

You must have code that is causing this behavior, as by default the HTML 5 form validation merely adds a `:valid` or `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class to the input field.

You can add custom CSS styling to reflect this state to the user as follows:

```
input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

---

You can read more about client-side input validation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: I want the message "Please match the format requested" to stay for longer period, right now it stays for short period of time.